# Bluemix Spark Service - Does it support spark streaming?

Tags: ibm-cloud, spark-streaming

Use the spark ipython boilerplate, is it possible to create spark streaming applications. Since the spark context is preconfigured with the notebook, this does not seem possible. I am trying a simple application:

```
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext._

val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(1))

val lines = ssc.socketTextStream("129.41.138.175", 9999)

// Split each line into words
val words = lines.flatMap(_.split(" "))

// Count each word in each batch
val pairs = words.map(word => (word, 1))
val wordCounts = pairs.reduceByKey(_ + _)

// Print the first ten elements of each RDD generated in this DStream 
wordCounts.print()

ssc.start()             // Start the computation
ssc.awaitTermination()  // Wait for the computation to terminate

Error:
Name: akka.actor.InvalidActorNameException
Message: actor name [JobScheduler] is not unique!
StackTrace: akka.actor.dungeon.ChildrenContainer$NormalChildrenContainer.reserve(ChildrenContainer.scala:130)
akka.actor.dungeon.Children$class.reserveChild(Children.scala:77)
akka.actor.ActorCell.reserveChild(ActorCell.scala:369)
akka.actor.dungeon.Children$class.makeChild(Children.scala:202)
akka.actor.dungeon.Children$class.attachChild(Children.scala:42)
akka.actor.ActorCell.attachChild(ActorCell.scala:369)
akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.actorOf(ActorSystem.scala:552)
org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler.start(JobScheduler.scala:58)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

We do support Spark streaming. It’s built into the Spark we deploy on Bluemix. But it depends on what Spark version and what language is used. Earlier Spark like 1.3.1 did not support streaming for python. The current version is 1.4.1.